# Checking if birthday falls within 7 days

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have two dictionaries set up like so

```
D = {'Jan': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Feb', 'prevmo': 'Dec'},
 'Feb': {'days': 29, 'nextmo': 'Mar', 'prevmo': 'Jan'},
 'Mar': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Apr', 'prevmo': 'Feb'},
 'Apr': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'May', 'prevmo': 'Mar'}, 
 'May': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Jun', 'prevmo': 'Apr'},
 'Jun': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Jul', 'prevmo': 'May'},
 'Jul': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Aug', 'prevmo': 'Jun'},
 'Aug': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Sep', 'prevmo': 'Jul'}, 
 'Sep': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Oct', 'prevmo': 'Aug'},
 'Oct': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Nov', 'prevmo': 'Sep'},
 'Nov': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Dec', 'prevmo': 'Nov'},
 'Dec': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Jan', 'prevmo': 'Jan'},}

birthdays =    {'John': ('Mar', 23, '1989'), 
'Johns_twin': ('Mar', 28, '1989'),
'Susan': ('Feb', 16, '1989'),
'Alan': ('Sep', 4, '1989'), 'Kevin': ('Dec', 23, '1989'), 'Murad': 
('Jan', 3, '1989'), 'Sandeep': ('Apr', 2, '1989'), 'James': ('Apr', 3, 
'1989'), 'Karen': ('Apr', 2, '1989'), 'Wiktoria': ('Jul', 14, '1989'), 
'Rogan': ('Jun', 29, '1989'), 'Fraser': ('Jan', 4, '1989'), 'Cameron': 
('Oct', 1, '1989')}
{'John': ('Mar', 23, '1989'), 'Johns_twin': ('Mar', 28, '1989')
```

Basically, if someone enters the date 'Apr' '2' I want it to return all birthdays within the range of 7 days (Mar 26 -> Apr 9)

I have most of the code working and know how to finish it, but the way I'm doing it seems extremely long. Is there a simpler solution (preferably without having to import datetime or any other modules)

The code I have thusfar from the function is as so. This is doing manual checks but to get it working for all scenarios the code will likely need to be 2-3x the length of this

```
def adder(bday_month_in,bday_day_in):
date_check1 = D[bday_month_in]['prevmo']
if 7 <= bday_day_in <= 21:
    max_bday = bday_day_in + 7
    min_bday = bday_day_in - 7
    print('The desired range is between', min_bday, 'and',max_bday, "of", bday_month_in)
    for key, (valX, valY, valZ) in birthdays.items():
        if valX == bday_month_in:
            if min_bday <= valY <= max_bday:
                print(key, (valX, valY, valZ))
else:
    if bday_day_in <= 6: #Apr 2
        adder = 7 - bday_day_in #5
        prev_mo = D[bday_month_in]['prevmo']  #month_max = Mar
        prev_date = D[prev_mo]['days'] - adder #days in mar (31) - 5 = 26
        print(prev_mo,prev_date)
        future_date = bday_day_in + 7
        print('The desired range is between', prev_date, "of", prev_mo,'and',future_date,bday_month_in)
        for key, (valX, valY, valZ) in birthdays.items():
            if future_date > valY and valX == bday_month_in:
                        print(key, (valX, valY, valZ))
            if valY > prev_date and valX == prev_mo:
                        print(key, (valX, valY, valZ))
    if bday_day_in => 21: #Apr 2
        adder = 7 - bday_day_in #5
        prev_mo = D[bday_month_in]['prevmo']  #month_max = Mar
        prev_date = D[prev_mo]['days'] - adder #days in mar (31) - 5 = 26
        print(prev_mo,prev_date)
        future_date = bday_day_in + 7
        print('The desired range is between', prev_date, "of", prev_mo,'and',future_date,bday_month_in)
        for key, (valX, valY, valZ) in birthdays.items():
            if future_date > valY and valX == bday_month_in:
                        print(key, (valX, valY, valZ))
            if valY > prev_date and valX == prev_mo:
                        print(key, (valX, valY, valZ))

                    #print('ValY',valY,valZ)
                   # print('prev_date',prev_date)
                  #  print('future_date',future_date)
                   # if future_date <= valY <= prev_date:

    else:
        valuer_max = days_in_that_month - 7
        month_max = D[bday_month_in]['prevmo']  # 'Mar'
        print(valuer_max,month_max)
```

Comment: Without use of a date/time module you will have to write the logic to deal with leap years. Does not seem efficient to me.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use `datetime`? It's there precisely to help with the craziness that is dates and times!

Comment: The main reason being that I had no year. The dictionary supplied originally was name/month/day. I added the year when trying to implement datetime but ended up going back to the method above. I would appreciate guidance on how it would work with datetime regardless as I couldnt get it to work as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this task without a date api is not trivial as the results depend on whether a leap day (29 February) is present or not.

This also means that for a correct result, one needs to know the year we are in. For example, if the reference day is 2 March, then in a non-leap year, 23 February falls in the 7 days range, but in a leap year it falls outside of it.

You really should make use of the `datetime` package, and convert your dates to such `datetime` objects.

Here is how your code could look:

```
import datetime

def around(birthdays, day, maxdays):
    result = []
    for name, bday in birthdays.items():
        try:
            mappedbday = bday.replace(year=day.year)
        except ValueError: # 29 February cannot be mapped to non-leap year
            mappedbday = bday.replace(year=day.year, day=28) # Choose 28-Feb instead
        if abs((mappedbday - day).days) <= maxdays:
            result.append((name, str(mappedbday)))
    return result


# Encode birthday values as datetime objects
birthdays = {
    'John': datetime.date(1989, 3, 23), 
    'Johns_twin': datetime.date(1989, 3, 28),
    'Susan': datetime.date(1989, 2, 16),
    'Alan': datetime.date(1989, 9, 4),
    'Kevin': datetime.date(1989, 12, 23), 
    'Murad': datetime.date(1989, 1, 3), 
    'Sandeep': datetime.date(1989, 4, 2), 
    'James': datetime.date(1989, 4, 3), 
    'Karen': datetime.date(1989, 4, 2), 
    'Wiktoria': datetime.date(1989, 7, 14),
    'Rogan': datetime.date(1989, 6, 29),
    'Fraser': datetime.date(1989, 1, 4),
    'Cameron': datetime.date(1989, 10, 1)
}

# Example:
month = 'Apr'
day = 2
# Convert month's abbreviated name to month number:
monthnum = datetime.datetime.strptime(month,'%b').month
# Create a date object: we need a year, as result may differ in leap year
refdate = datetime.date(2018, monthnum, day)

print(around(birthdays, refdate, 7))
```

The output for the above example:

```
[('Johns_twin', '2018-03-28'), 
 ('Sandeep', '2018-04-02'), 
 ('James', '2018-04-03'), 
 ('Karen', '2018-04-02')]
```

The dates are just formatted with the `str` function, but you can of course choose to format them differently.